# I have some trouble in adding cell into UITableView with storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Liked the picture below.

[image]

It appears a square which is marked with a red box when I add a custom cell into my UITableView. I don't know why. Anyone can tell me?

Comment: also provide the code of tableview delegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have added a UIView inside the UITableView (above the prototype cells). You can check this in the Document Outline view:

[image: Document Outline View]

You can select it and delete it if you don't needed.